# valid regular regular expression string

Tags: .net, regex, validation-controls

Hi I have a regular expression which is strated failing now. not sure what is stopping.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+\\[\w- ]+[$])|(\\{2}\w+))(\\[\w-. ]*)*(.xml|.XML)$");

if (!regex.IsMatch(fuSource.PostedFile.FileName))
{
      Page.Validators.Add(new ValidatorHelper("Please select a valid Application XML input file."));
}
```

the file name i am passing is:

`XX2 03-01-2017.xml`

But for some reason it is not taking.

please help with the valid file name that matches the pattern..

Comment: Can you provide the format of input file name?

Comment: What is hapenning exactly? Your regex matches `c:\XX2 03-01-2017.xml` or `\\c\XX2 03-01-2017.xml`.

Comment: this is my input "XX2 03-01-2017.xml"

Comment: the error is firing. i am selecting a file from my local drive and file name is "XX2 03-01-2017.xml". i thnk the file name is not maching the pattern.

Comment: Sure, it does not. What are the requirements for the file name? Try [`^(?:(?:[a-zA-Z]:|\\{2}\w+\\[\w -]+[$]|\\{2}\w+)\\)?[\w. -]*\.(?:xml|XML)$`](https://regex101.com/r/9k5UYD/1) but I think it might not be doing what you expect it to.

Comment: its an existing code base. i need to provide the file name which matches the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test your regex on an online tool like this one to try it yourself :
https://regex101.com/r/UX9TjE/1

Basically your regexp matches 3 parts in the filename :

- The prefix :  It can be 3 things

  - A windows-like drive name : `c:` or `Z:`
  - A windows shared drive with parameter : `\\shared\user$`
  - A windows shared drive : `\\shared`
- The name (note: it can be empty, ie zero-length) :

  - It includes the path of the file, using backslashes, and it can have spaces :
  - `\my\path\my file`
- The extension : `.xml` or `.XML`

IMHO this regex is not very good, here are some example matches :

```
c:\path\\XX2 03-01-2017.xml

\\nas\user$\XX2 03-01-2017.xml

\\network_shared\.xml

\\a.XML
```

You can see why each one matches here :
https://regex101.com/r/UX9TjE/2